# Gulp-nodemon watch files: node: bad option: -e js,html,hbs

Tags: gulp

I don't know whats happening but it won't accept arguments. I'm using NVM using node version 0.12. Any other details you need just shout.

```
[07:31:27] Starting 'watch'...
[07:31:30] Finished 'watch' after 3.07 s
[07:31:30] Finished 'dev-local' after 16 s
[07:31:30] [nodemon] v1.3.7
[07:31:30] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[07:31:30] [nodemon] watching: *.*
[07:31:30] [nodemon] starting `node -e js,html,hbs -w ../dist -w ../dist/public -w ../dist/public/img -w ../dist/public/js -w ../dist/views -w ../dist/routes -w ../dist/partials -w ../dist/layouts --harmony ../dist/app.js`
node: bad option: -e js,html,hbs
[07:31:30] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
[07:31:31] Starting 'reload'...
reload
[07:31:31] index.html reloaded.
[07:31:31] Finished 'reload' after 1.36 ms
```

Here is my gulpfile.js code:

```
gulp.task('nodemon', function () {
    nodemon({
        script: '../dist/app.js',
        nodeArgs: ['-e js,html,hbs', ' -w ../dist -w ../dist/public -w ../dist/public/img -w ../dist/public/js -w ../dist/views -w ../dist/routes -w ../dist/partials -w ../dist/layouts', '--harmony']
    }).on('start', function () {
        setTimeout(function delay() {
            gulp.start('reload');
        }, 400);
    });

    gulp.watch('../dist/**', ['reload']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `execMap` config entry instead of `nodeArgs`, e.g.:

```
"execMap": {
    "js": "node --harmony"
},
```